# blocking website in my country where it has been copied a lot

Tags: seo, google, google-search, security

I have an issue that my website has been copying in my country. i want to block in my country. does it impact on SEO?

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify what you mean by "impact on SEO" (e.g., impact it where - globally, your own country...). We'll also need to know whether your domain is a gTLD or a ccTLD (for your own country or region), if you've targeted it for a country in Google Search Console, and how you intend on blocking your website and from whom (just visitors, Google, etc...).